# How to access the following SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a training matrix for my company that shows all employees with all training courses provided in the company. Now, I have to develop it in such a way to be easy to edit and update by the admin. I did everything correct except one thing which is giving each group of courses a specific color (since I have 3 types of courses). FYI, I have two SqlDataSources for developing this matrix:

**SqlDataSource1 is for retrieving the GroupID:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [groups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**And the SqlDataSource2 will take the GroupID from the SqlDataSource1 and use it to generate the matrix:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport" FilterExpression="[Division] like '{0}%'">

                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID"/>
                            </SelectParameters>

                            <FilterParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                                                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, since I am using HTMLTable, I need to access the SqlDataSource1 to do some logic like:
if the GroupID = 1, then give this group Blue color and so on. But I don't know how to do that. **So could you please help me with this issue?**

My code-behind in C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView group in dv2)
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = group[0].ToString();
            //create a new HtmlTable object
            HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

            DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            int columns = dv.Table.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dv.Count;

            //table's formating-related properties
            table.Border = 2;
            table.CellPadding = 3;
            table.CellSpacing = 3;
            table.Width = "900px";

            //to get the css style
            table.Attributes["class"] = "uGrid";

            //create a new HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell objects
            HtmlTableRow row;
            HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell;


            //for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);

            //loop for adding rows to the table
            foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
            {
                row = new HtmlTableRow();
                //row.BgColor = "yellow";


                //loop for adding cells
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    if (j < 4)
                    {
                        cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

                        int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
                        string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
                        string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                        string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                        checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
                        checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
                        cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                    }

                    //add the cell to the current row
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                //add the row to the table
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //add the table to the page
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);

        }
    }
```

I tried to do it by doing the following but I failed:

```
//for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;
                if (group[0].Equals(1)){
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Blue";
                else if (group[0].Equals(2))
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Yellow";
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, ***is it possible to determine which cells will be colored with Blue?*** For example, In Group#1 which has 8 courses, I want the coloring to start from the fourth cell up to the last one. Whereas, Group#2 which has 10 courses, also, I want the coloring to be start from the fourth cell up to the last one. ***Could you please help me with this issue?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell, did you make sure that first *DataRowViews* item from your DataView correspond to **GroupId** in your query? And have you tried applying `ToString()` method to value that you retrieve from first item of DataRowView in the last code snippet, like in following:

```
if (group[0].ToString().Equals("1"))
    headerCell.BgColor = "Blue";
```

Also, to change color of your rows in table - you need to change color of fields with data - or even better the whole rows, instead of changing color of headers.

**Edit:**

To change table's data field background color you can assign [BgColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell.bgcolor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of [HtmlTableCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instances while populating table - like in following:

```
        if (j < 4)
        {
            cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

            int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
            string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
            string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
            string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
            checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
            checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
            cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);

            // set field background color  
            if (group[0].Equals(1)){
                cell.BgColor = "Blue";
            else if (group[0].Equals(2))
                cell.BgColor = "Yellow";
            }
```

**Edit 2:**

To set color of header cells I would recommend to replase usage of Equals method with equality operator (starting from column with certain index):

```
        //for adding the headers to the table

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
        {
            HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
            headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;

            if (++counter >= 5)
            {
                if (int.Parse(group[0]) == 1){
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Blue";
                else if (int.Parse(group[0]) == 2)
                    headerCell.BgColor = "Yellow";
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
        }
        table.Rows.Add(header);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. By the way, is it possible to determine which cells will be colored with Blue? For example, In Group#1 which has 8 courses, I want the coloring to start from the fourth cell up to the last one. Whereas, Group#2 which has 10 courses, also, I want the coloring to be start from the fourth cell up to the last one. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: @AliAhmed It is possible to change color of a table field with [BgColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell.bgcolor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of HtmlTableCell class. You can assign it in `else` block of your `if` operator in code snippet where you are looping through DataView. Near comment `//loop for adding cells` - in your thrird code snippet - where HtmlTable is created.

Comment: Thanks but I am talking about the Header Cells not the Rows cells. Could you please provide me with the code snippet?

Comment: @AliAhmed Your code seems to be ok for setting header color - you need to make sure that: 1. your group number is trigerred properly - e.g. is extracted from DataRowView and correctly compared to value that you supply - to be sure that color gets assigned to header fields and 2. colour takes effect in Html markup of the table.

Comment: this is not what I mean. What I want is for the HeaderCells I want to give the specific color starting from the fourth cell in each table. So how to do that?

Comment: @AliAhmed The simpliest way is to define `int` counter variable with value `0` before start of the loop and then: 1. increase it in each loop iteration and 2. set cell color depending on value of counter variable - see updated answer.